# Create Angular component from backend Interface

Tags: angular, typescript

Suppose I have an Angular app with a Typescript backend. This app will edit Steps as defined below:

```
export type Action = 'One' | 'Two' | 'Three' 
export interface Step {
  name: string,
  action: Action,
  value?: string,
  identifier?: {
    xpath?: string,
    id?: string
  }
}
```

And I want to define an Angular component to create/edit an instance of that interface. Is there a way to define the component class automatically from the interface, or do I need to create it manually, as in the below?

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core'
import { Step } from 'backend/src/libs/step.ts'
@Component({
  selector: 'app-test-step',
  templateUrl: './test-step.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test-step.component.css']
}
export class StepComponent { 
  private name: Step['name']
  private action: Step['action']
  ...
}
```

Comment: You could probably make a custom [schematic](https://angular.io/guide/schematics-authoring) to generate

Comment: There is no such way to generate a component from an interface definition.

Comment: I imagine a schematic could read a file, just as an interface, parse out the fields/types and generate a class based on that.

Comment: If the interface is not changing then you can just create the component to edit it. There's no need to add extra complexity if it's not going to change. If the interface is ever changing, and would come from an API (so not an interface but a definition from backend), then you can build a dynamic form generator based on that interface. Or use some solution from the market for schema form generation.

Comment: have a look at 'ts-morph' and '@phenomnomnominal/tsquery' packages.
One option is use these packages and write component files.  I am using these packages for parsing ts files.  But if your requirement is to have just a selector for each component without any specific logic, may be you can look at creating customElement rather than angular components